# jquery focus does not work in ajax loaded content

Tags: jquery, ajax, angularjs

I am trying to set focus on element which was generated using ajax `.load` method.

**DesignHome.aspx**

```
<!-- All Jquery Scripts Go Here -->
<script src="../../Scripts/angular.min.js?v=7" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var app = angular.module("module", []);
</script>
<script src="../../Scripts/DataFactory/DataFactory.js?v=7" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../../Scripts/Controller/RegistrationController.js?v=7" type="text/javascript"></script>

<div id="divPopupRegistration" class="RegistrationPopup hide" style="overflow: hidden;
    z-index: 999" ng-app="module">  
    <div id="divFullRegistration" class="Full hide">
    </div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function partialRegistrationForm() {
        $('#divFullRegistration').load('../RegistrationPages/PartialRegistration.htm', function (data) {
            $('input[name=firstname]').focus();
        });
    }
</script>
```

PartialRegistration.htm

```
<!-- Again i have to load this, if i wont then it will not work. Reason unknown -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../Scripts/angular.min.js?v=7.0.0"></script>

<body ng-cloak>
    <div ng-controller="partialcontroller" id="parentDiv" ng-init="init()">
        <div class="registrationBg" runat="server" id="PartialRegistration">
            <div class="regcontent">
                <ul class="bxslider">
                    <li id="liContact">
                        <form name="formContactInfoPartial" novalidate>
                        <div class="popupContent" id="ContactInfo">
                            <div class="left column1">
                                <div class="lable">
                                    First Name<span>*</span></div>
                                <input type="text" class="textbox shareinput" ng-model="UserDetails.firstName" name="firstname"
                                    onkeypress="return isAlphabet(event);" ng-required="true" tabindex="0" maxlength="20"
                                    ng-class="{'has-error': submitted && formContactInfoPartial.firstname.$invalid}" />
                            </div>

<!-- Then all remaining markup and closing tags -->

<script>
    // My focus code breaks here !
</script>
```

Error what i am getting

**Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded**

What i tried as alternate

```
$('input[name="firstname"]').on("focus", function () { });
```

AND

```
setTimeout(function () { $('input[name="firstname"]').focus(); }, 500);
```

But it doesnt work for me.

Comment: did you try to target document  `$(document)` rather than `$('input[name="firstname"]')` for event delegation

Comment: @NorlihazmeyGhazali : do u mean by this - `$('input[name="firstname"]',document).on("focus", function () { });`

Comment: this `$(document).on("focus",'input[name="firstname"]', function () { });`

Comment: Maybe you should add the angularjs tag to your question

Comment: And how many `input[name=firstname]` are there on the page? Try to target exactly one to focus, this error message should appear only if you have many inputs, or if you are inside an infinite loop. How and when do you call the `partialRegistrationForm()`? If you trigger ajax call on input focus, than you have an infinite loop - you should check XHR requests in Inspector.

Comment: @skobaljic : There are only one element `input[name=firstname]`. function  `partialRegistrationForm()` get called on `click` of a button. I am triggering ajax call on click of button, which loads the document inside `div`

Comment: Have you checked the inspector, how many requests are there on button click? Look, your code here is correct, so there must something else... inside the code that you haven't posted. Maybe you declared `load` many times.

Comment: @Shaggy Enable javascript profiling on your browser and reproduce the problem. Since it seems an infinite recursion, it'll blame what code was most using CPU until the maximum call stack size exceeded.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- @Shaggy Why are you using an Ajax to obtain the template? If you
  inject HTML manually without using Angular you are risking the cycles
  of `$apply` and `$digest` correctly and the data bind.

  Using AngularJS what you should do is:

  - Use `ng-include` to add the template whenever you need it to.(*Also would work using `ng-transclude`*)
  - Create a attribute `directive` to receive focus

In [this example](http://plnkr.co/edit/sLfvUz?p=preview) the template is added when you press the button

```
  <div id="divFullRegistration" ng-include="partialTemplate" class="Full hide"></div>
```

And add a get-focus directive on your template

```
<input get-focus="true"/>
```

I hope this helps you. If you want to do it using `ng-transclude` or `directives` let us know.

Regards

Comment: i have edited my question to give u better picture . link u provided is not working. can u give me some example on ng-transclude & directives

Comment: I checked the previous example, works fine, can you make a plnkr of how you implement the ng-include? Because that might be the more cleaner solution.

Comment: About the focus, you only need to implement an "auto-focus" directive or similar, just like the previous example, no matter which method you use for load your template, [Example using ng-if of auto focus](http://plnkr.co/edit/qno79p?p=preview) and this is an [Example using 2 Directives with ng-transclude](http://plnkr.co/edit/BoXTL2?p=preview)

Answer (score 2):

give you'r input and form id, and run this code

```
$('#formId').find('#inputId').focus();
```

Answer (score 0):

Give your input an id and than try this

```
<input type="text" class="textbox shareinput" id="firstName" / >
$('input[id$=firstName]').foucs();
```

This should work.

Answer (score 0):

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $('input[name=firstname]').focus();
});
```

full example

```
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script>
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $('input[name=firstname]').focus();
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<input type="text" name="firstname" />
</body>
</html>
```

https://api.jquery.com/focus/

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$(function(){
  $('#target').load('load.html', function(){
    $('input[name="name"]', $('#target')).focus();
  });
})
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/6zaymsYyIHtOs6LxZRw2

Answer (score 0):

you can set focus by using html5 too

```
<input type="text" class="textbox shareinput" ng-model="UserDetails.firstName" name="firstname" autofocus>
```